# Key Permissions in Azure Key Vault

Tags: access-control, azure-keyvault

Was exploring the Azure Key Vault Key permissions and one thing where I stuck is - What is the meaning of **"List"**- **key permission** while setting up this parameter in **Access policy** section?
It would be good if one can provide the documentation link for all the available key permission in the access policy. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add the `"List"- key permission` for the user/group/service principal in the  `Access policies`, they will be able to list the keys in your keyvault.

For all the available key permissions, you could see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.keyvault/set-azkeyvaultaccesspolicy?view=azps-4.1.0#parameters

[image]

Comment: Thanks Joy! Just one doubt though, then can we Get & List is more over one and the same?

Comment: @Abhi I think Get & List are more than List.

Comment: As I understand it, the 'list' operation allows you to see properties of the key (or secrets in the case of list secrets), but not the (secret) values.The 'get' operation allows you to see the values of a particular key. At least this is how the python API works: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/master/sdk/keyvault/azure-keyvault-keys#list-keys